# Can't boot to Mac OS volume after Bootcamp Windows install

Tags: macos, bootcamp, startup, mojave

I've installed Windows 10 with Bootcamp on a new iMac with Mojave.

Now I can't boot to MacOS volume.

1) Bootcamp tool in Windows don't see volume as bootable.

2) Option click on restart don't show a menu to choose, only when bootable usb is connected

3) If I boot to installation USB, I can see this volume, but Startup can't choose this volume: The bless tool was unable to set the current boot disk...

I read some bootloader repair guide with changing partition size, but I don't know how to do that with hybrid drive.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't wiped the macOS volume when you installed Windows?

Comment: I'm sure. I can see it in 3)

Answer (score 1):

Some strange thing happened.

I switched iMac off (like I did before for several times to restart) and let it be off for a time while I compiled fresh Mojave installation usb drive.

And after turning on iMac started to react on Option key, so I could choose MacOs volume to boot and it's booted successfully. Usb installation flash was plugged in.

Now this Option key boot menu is available without usb-flash plugged in...